# function getContents() returning unexpected results

Tags: php

I wrote a function called getContents():

```
// Get contents of specific DIR.  Will recur through all directories.
function getContents($path, $skip_dir = FALSE, $skip_files = "", $dir_only = FALSE, $recurse = TRUE) 
{   if($skip_files == "") $skip_files = array();
    $getContentsTmp = array();
    foreach(scandir($path, 1) as $file) 
    {   
        if(($file != ".") && ($file != "..")) 
        {   if((is_file($path . "/" . $file)) && (!in_array(pathinfo($path . "/" . $file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION),$skip_files)) && (!$dir_only))  {
                array_push($getContentsTmp, $file);
            }
            if((is_dir($path . "/" . $file)) && (!$skip_dir)) {
                if($recurse) {
                    $getContentsTmp[$file] = getContents($path . "/" . $file, $skip_files, $dir_only, $recurse);
                } else {
                    array_push($getContentsTmp,$file); 
                    // or $getContentsTmp[$file] = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ksort($getContentsTmp);
    return $getContentsTmp;
}
```

It's worked fine for a long time.  But for some reason I go to use it on another directory today, and it's not returning the expected results.  I have narrowed it down to the `$dir_only` variable.  For some reason it is passing through as true, even if I don't set it.  I don't change the variable anywhere, so I don't know why this is happening.

The call to the function is this:

`$e = getContents("my_dir");`

If I echo out the results in the function, It is seeing all the files and folder's correctly, but when it goes to call the function again from inside itself, (after `if($recurse)`), It passes through $dir_only but that seems to get interpreted as true.  I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at how many parameters you pass in:

```
getContents($path . "/" . $file, $skip_files, $dir_only, $recurse);
                      ^              ^            ^         ^
                      1              2            3         4
```

Look how many your function accepts:

```
getContents($path, $skip_dir = FALSE, $skip_files = "", $dir_only = FALSE, $recurse = TRUE) 
             ^           ^               ^                     ^                ^
             1           2               3                     4                5
```

So in this case, you are calling the function and missed `$skip_dir`, and therefore the value of `$recurse` is being applied to the argument `$dir_only`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I would have never seen this :)